# EF Exception - InvalidOperationException: The 'x' property on 'y' could not be set to a 'String' value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Another developer has added a new non-null int property (OrderItemSource) to one of our EF Model Entities (OrderItem).

Our application is throwing an exception when trying to load OrderItems from the DB.

> [InvalidOperationException: The 'OrderItemSource' property on 'OrderItem' could not be set to a 'String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'. ]
>
> System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) +218 ....

- The property is an int not null type in the DB and is accessed directly on the table.
- On the application side OrderItemSource is represented as an enum value and is abstracted with a partial class by following property

  ```
  public CartItem.SourceType Source
  {
      get { return (CartItem.SourceType)OrderItemSource; }
      set { OrderItemSource = (int)value; }
  }
  ```
- The EF generated code looks ok as in it has created a property with type Int32.

The Model looks like this:

```
<Property Name="OrderItemSource" Type="int" Nullable="false" />

<Property Type="Int32" Name="OrderItemSource" Nullable="false" />

<ScalarProperty Name="OrderItemSource"  ColumnName="OrderItemSource" />
```

Can anyone see why this might be throwing the exception? The types look ok from DB, through to EF and my partial.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: have you tried cheking the model edmx

Answer (score 2):

Noob moment - It would be good if I checked the right database. 
The type on the database was actually a varchar, it was out of synch with the DB project.